# Dynamically resizing and placing div at the end (right/bottom) of container

Tags: html, css

I have this setup

HTML:

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.cont{  
  border:solid 1px red;
  display:inline-block;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  height: 30px;
  border:solid 1px #000;
}

.big{
  width:600px;
}
  
.right {
  border:solid 1px #000;
  min-width:200px;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 30px;
  padding-left:5px;
  padding-right:10px;
  padding-top:3px;
  background:green
}
```

```html
<div class='cont'>
  <div class='left'>1</div>
  <div class='left'>2</div>
  <div class='left big'>3</div> 
  <div class='left big'>4</div> 
  <div class='right'>Dynamic Div</div>
</div>
```

[Codepen link](http://codepen.io/rishadjb/pen/bwVZbv) for those who prefer that

I need the 'right' div to be placed on the right of div 4. What happens is, if there is leftover space of >=200px after placing the numbered divs, the input text div gets squeezed in there. I don't want that.

Essentially the 'right' div always needs to be on the right of the last numbered div, and filling in the remaining space on the right. If the remaining space is less than 200px, the div should move to the next row.

Each of the numbered divs will have varied widths, although that probably doesn't matter here.

Can I achieve this without jquery?

Thanks.

EDIT: I was able to get this done using flexbox

```css
.cont{  
    border:solid 1px red;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.right {
    flex-grow:1;
    border:solid 1px #000;
  .....
}
```

Comment: This sounds like something that [CSS's flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) may be perfect for.

Comment: I must be missing something, because otherwise just adding `float:right;` to your `.right` class accomplishes what I think you're asking?

Comment: float:right, sets it to right, but doesn't resize the div. It keeps it at the min-width, instead of resizing it to the leftover space.

Comment: Flexbox worked. Thanks. Added the answer in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using flex boxes it is possible to get this done.

View it on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gp8yjrhy/1/).

Snippet (updated with width: fit-content):

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.cont {
  border: solid 1px red;
  /*display: inline-block;*/
  display: flex; /* added */
  flex-wrap: wrap; /* added */
  
  width: -webkit-fit-content; /* chrome 22+, opera 15+, safari 6.1+ */
  width: -moz-fit-content; /* firefox 3+ */
  width: fit-content; /* default */
}

.left {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  /*width: 300px;*/
  min-width: 300px; /* added */
  max-width: 300px; /* added */
  box-sizing: border-box; /* added */
}

.big {
  /*width: 600px;*/
  max-width: 600px; /* added */
  min-width: 600px; /* added */
}

.right {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  min-width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 30px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  background: green;
  flex: 1; /* added */
}
```

```html
<div class='cont'>
  <div class='left'>1</div>
  <div class='left'>2</div>
  <div class='left big'>3</div>
  <div class='left big'>4</div>
  <div class='right'>Dynamic Div</div>
</div>
```

You can learn more about flexboxes from these links:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be working without having to add the min and max widths for the numbered divs.

Comment: Updated with `width: fit-content`, this will fix the red line being over the numbered divs. --- I had added the min/max because flex will essentially ignore the width, so the div would collapse and become smaller than 300px/600px respectively. If you don't mind them getting smaller than the width you've assigned, you can remove the min/max. With `width: fit-content` though, min/max width is not needed as the main div would be automatically resized to fit all.